# Перехват запросов посредством "JS" в "Chrome"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, requests

Как можно сделать перехват запросов посредством JS в "Chrome" ? Например, чтобы на любой запрос на какой-то или на все сайты мне возвращалась строка "this is a response constructed by VPN extension".

Comment: На любой запрос откуда? С сайта? Из консоли браузера? Со всех сайтов?

Comment: Со всех сайтов, Александр. Например, набираю какой-нибудь сайт в поиске и после его загрузки появляется данная строка. Теперь Вам более понятно стало или по-прежнему нет ?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону раширений для браузера. Я в этом не силен, поэтому больше ничего не подскажу)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо Вам большое за ответ, Александр! Я просто смотрел но ничего адекватного не мог найти в итоге... Вообще моя задача более обширная, если честно...:(((